# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm new to pyton. I got trubles with telegram bot.
if i'm only send file everything works fine, but when i start from begining with entering data and generating pdf file and after that send file in bot my code crush with error:

```
2022-10-17 12:19:54,164 (__init__.py:878 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: 'NoneType' object is not callable"
ERROR:TeleBot:Infinity polling exception: 'NoneType' object is not callable
2022-10-17 12:19:54,167 (__init__.py:880 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 875, in infinity_polling
    logger_level=logger_level, allowed_updates=allowed_updates, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 947, in polling
    logger_level=logger_level, allowed_updates=allowed_updates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1021, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 977, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 154, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 98, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
"
ERROR:TeleBot:Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 875, in infinity_polling
    logger_level=logger_level, allowed_updates=allowed_updates, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 947, in polling
    logger_level=logger_level, allowed_updates=allowed_updates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 1021, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 977, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 154, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/telebot/util.py", line 98, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import io
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from datetime import date
import email, smtplib, ssl
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = 'bot token'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
current_date = date.today()
print(current_date)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m, res=False):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Я на связи. Как тебя зовут? )')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_name(message):
  bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введи серию и номер паспорта?");
  global name
  name = message.text
  print(name)
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_passport_serial);
def get_passport_serial(message):
  bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введи кем и когда выдан паспорт");
  global number
  number = message.text
  print(name)
  print(number)
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_passport_info);
def get_passport_info(message):
  bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введи адрес регистрации");
  global info
  info = message.text
  print(name, number, info)
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_passport_adress);
def get_passport_adress(message):
  bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Жди");
  global adress
  adress = message.text
  print(name, number, info, adress)
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, send_PDF(message, name, number, info, adress));
def send_PDF(message, name, number, info, adress):
  checkSend = False
  print("отправлено")
  while checkSend == False:
    try:
      f = open("original" + str(message.from_user.id) + ".pdf","rb")
      bot.send_document(message.chat.id,f)
      checkSend = True
      if os.path.isfile("original" + str(message.from_user.id) + ".pdf"): 
        os.remove("original" + str(message.from_user.id) + ".pdf") 
        print("success") 
      else: print("File doesn't exists!")


    except FileNotFoundError:
      print('write')
      pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('DejaVuSerif','DejaVuSerif.ttf', 'UTF-8'))
      packet = io.BytesIO()
      can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
      can.setFont('DejaVuSerif', 10)
      can.drawString(150, 785, name)
      can.drawString(130, 755, number)
      can.drawString(250, 755, info)
      can.drawString(210, 727, adress)
      can.drawString(130, 200, str(current_date))
      can.save()

      #move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
      packet.seek(0)

      # create a new PDF with Reportlab
      new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
      # read your existing PDF
      existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open("destination.pdf", "rb"))
      output = PdfFileWriter()
      # add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
      page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
      page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
      output.addPage(page)
      # finally, write "output" to a real file
      outputStream = open("original" + str(message.from_user.id) + ".pdf", "wb")
      output.write(outputStream)
      outputStream.close()
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def sender_email(message):
  print("file accepted")
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. If someone interested problem was in bot.register_next_step_handler. It can't provide arguments if function so instead of this:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(message, send_PDF(message, name, number, info, adress))
```

I made this:

```
send_PDF(message, name, number, info, adress)
```

And now everithing works fine. Thanks myself for this)